# Condition trowing error and how use here without any error

Tags: java, error-handling

My repository code

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Event>{

    List<Event> findByStatus(String status);

    Page<Event> findByStatus(String status, Pageable pageable);
}
```

my service class

```
public ApiResponse upcommingEvent(String filter){
    return new ApiResponse(LocalDateTime.now(), HttpStatus.OK, "some",  eventRepository.findAll(new Specification<Event>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Event> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if(filter!=null) {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("eventDateStart"), filter)));
            } 
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }
    }));
}
```

Here eventRepository.findAll(new Specification()) is default function but i need to findByStatus("Y") condition. When i use findByStatus condition trowing error and how use here without any error.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Pls, show us whole your code with `findByStatus("Y")` usage. Also, pls, provide full package name for `ApiResponse`. Is it Swagger class, right?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query.